# Getting the latest values for grouped items within the given period, incl. zeros and nulls

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Would you please help me to find out whether I am on the right way? I am new to SQL, so there many things that are not obvious to me.

Let's assume I have two tables.
The first is a list of subscribers:

```
      subscribers
+--------+------------+
|subscID |    name    |
+--------+------------+
|   123  | SomeName00 |
|   456  | SomeName01 |
|   789  | SomeName02 |
|   012  | SomeName03 |
|   345  | SomeName04 |
+--------+------------+
```

And the second is a call log (or something like that), including the subscribers' incomes and expenditures with transaction IDs and the current state of their accounts:

```
                        transactions
+--------+---------------------+--------+-----------+----------+
| trnID  | date                |subscID | amount    | balance  |
+--------+---------------------+-------+------------+----------+
| 321456 | 2012-03-13 11:10:00 |   456  |   70.0000 |  90.0000 |
| 234567 | 2012-03-16 15:05:00 |   456  |  -45.0000 |  45.0000 |
| 345678 | 2012-03-19 17:27:00 |   456  |   15.0000 |  60.0000 |
| 654321 | 2012-04-22 17:34:00 |   456  |  -10.0000 |  50.0000 |
| 543210 | 2012-04-15 15:45:00 |   789  |   20.0000 |  30.0000 |
| 567890 | 2012-05-16 13:30:00 |   789  |  -10.0000 |  20.0000 |
| 876543 | 2012-02-29 11:00:00 |   012  |   20.0000 |   5.0000 |
| 678901 | 2012-03-31 09:40:00 |   012  |   10.0000 |  15.0000 |
| 456789 | 2012-03-31 21:09:00 |   012  |  -13.0000 |   2.0000 |
| 432109 | 2012-02-23 14:01:00 |   345  |  -30.0000 |  27.0000 |
| 012345 | 2012-03-24 19:57:00 |   345  |   40.0000 |  67.0000 |
| 765432 | 2012-03-27 13:28:00 |   345  |  -14.0000 |  53.0000 |
+--------+---------------------+--------+-----------+----------+
```

---

Initially I had two **tasks**:

**1.** To count the number of transactions for every subscriber for
    March 2012 (including those from the first table who are not in the
    second table, like `123 SomeName00`, and those who didn't have any
    transactions in March 2012, like `789 SomeName02`).

**2.** To count the ending balance for every subscriber for March 2012
    (again, including those from the first table who are not in the
    second table and those who didn't have any transactions in March
    2012).

---

I've handled the first one this way:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(transactions.subscID) AS num_of_trns
FROM subscribers
LEFT JOIN transactions
ON subscribers.subscID = transactions.subscID 
    AND transactions.date LIKE "2012-03%"
GROUP BY subscribers.subscID
```

It seems to work, giving the following result:

```
+------------+------------+
|    name    |num_of_trns |
+------------+------------+
| SomeName00 |     0      |
| SomeName01 |     3      |
| SomeName02 |     0      |
| SomeName03 |     2      |
| SomeName04 |     2      |
+------------+------------+
```

Then I tried to reuse the code so that to solve the second task by changing `COUNT(transactions.subscID)` to `transactions.balance` and adding one more condition to LEFT JOIN (`transactions.date = MAX(transactions.date)`), like this:

```
SELECT name, transactions.balance AS trns_blnc
FROM subscribers
LEFT JOIN transactions
ON subscribers.subscID = transactions.subscID 
    AND transactions.date LIKE "2012-03%"
    AND transactions.date = MAX(transactions.date) --this is incorrect
GROUP BY subscribers.subscID
```

But this approach turned out to be absolutely wrong (I suppose, MySQL just didn't understand which values I was trying to compare).

Then I decided to make use of the first task result by once again left-joining another instance of `transactions` to it (sorry if I use the wrong terminology) on the condition that the instance's date = the old table's date:

```
SELECT march_trns.name, balance FROM (
    SELECT name, date
    FROM subscribers
    LEFT JOIN transactions
    ON subscribers.subscID = transactions.subscID 
        AND transactions.date LIKE "2012-03%"
        GROUP BY subscribers.subscID
) AS march_trns
LEFT JOIN transactions AS transactions2
ON march_trns.date = transactions2.date
```

But quickly learned that `march_trns.date` and, as a result, `balance` was selected randomly (or I just failed to find out any pattern in its selection) among the values, meeting the `LIKE "2012-03%"` condition. Moreover, there were NULLs in my resulting table (I guess, it's because I was no longer using `COUNT` that would count all the rows, incl. NULLs):

```
          Have:                          Want:
+------------+----------+      +------------+----------+
| name       | balance  |      | name       | balance  |
+------------+----------+      +------------+----------+
| SomeName00 |     NULL |      | SomeName00 |   0.0000 |
| SomeName01 |  90.0000 |      | SomeName01 |  60.0000 |
| SomeName02 |     NULL |      | SomeName02 |   0.0000 |
| SomeName03 |   2.0000 |      | SomeName03 |   2.0000 |
| SomeName04 |  67.0000 |      | SomeName04 |  53.0000 |
+------------+----------+      +------------+----------+
```

So, I have two problems:

- I need to retrieve the end month balance values
- and to print out the NULL values as `0`s.

I would be much obliged to you if you show me the right direction.

Comment: It's not a big surprise that your query appears to return random results. What you have written is not valid standard SQL, but a MySQL specific extension. You would probably find this page in the documentation enlightening: [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html).

Comment: `+1` for asking very clear question, providing sample records with desired result `:D`.

Comment: @Mark Byers Thank you, I'll read the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  name, 
        COALESCE(COUNT(transactions.subscID), 0) AS num_of_trns,
        COALESCE(d.balance,0)
FROM    subscribers
        LEFT JOIN transactions
            ON subscribers.subscID = transactions.subscID 
                AND transactions.date LIKE "2012-03%"
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.subscID, a.balance
            FROM    transactions a
                    INNER JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT subscID, MAX(date) maxDate
                        FROM transactions
                        WHERE transactions.date LIKE "2012-03%"
                        GROUP BY subscID
                    ) b ON a.subscID = b.subscID AND
                            a.date = b.maxDate

        ) d ON subscribers.subscID = d.subscID
GROUP BY subscribers.subscID
ORDER BY Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18c77/3)

or by using `YEAR` and `MONTH`

```
SELECT  name, 
        COALESCE(COUNT(transactions.subscID), 0) AS num_of_trns,
        COALESCE(d.balance,0)
FROM    subscribers
        LEFT JOIN transactions
            ON subscribers.subscID = transactions.subscID 
                AND YEAR(transactions.date) = 2012 AND
                    MONTH(transactions.date) = 3
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.subscID, a.balance
            FROM    transactions a
                    INNER JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT subscID, MAX(date) maxDate
                        FROM transactions
                        WHERE YEAR(transactions.date) = 2012 AND
                              MONTH(transactions.date) = 3
                        GROUP BY subscID
                    ) b ON a.subscID = b.subscID AND
                            a.date = b.maxDate

        ) d ON subscribers.subscID = d.subscID
GROUP BY subscribers.subscID
ORDER BY Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18c77/4)

**SOURCE**

- [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)
- [MONTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)
- [YEAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

Comment: Thank you, John, I've just tried the first version. It returns the right values for march transactions, but there are still NULLs for the rest :-(

Comment: I can, but... What is the 'records' in this case? :-) Anyway, your second query works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Returning to my previous complaint, either I mistakenly deleted some characters or copied the code before your edition, but there was only 'd.balance' on the third line instead of 'COALESCE(d.balance,0)'. Sorry for misleading.